# Java / Spring MVC 3 validation of an email address

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc

I have a Java backend with Spring MVC and I am using validation in this way on my domain object for an email address:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
...
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 100)
@Pattern(regexp="^([a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.\\_]+)'+'(\\@)([a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]+)'+'(\\.)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})$")
private String email;
```

But all I get with these lines of code

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<Person>> failures = validator.validate(personObject);
...
Map<String, String> failureMessages = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (ConstraintViolation<Person> failure : failures) {
    failureMessages.put(failure.getPropertyPath().toString(), failure.getMessage());
    System.out.println(failure.getPropertyPath().toString()+" - "+failure.getMessage())
}
```

I get this on the console:

```
email - must match "^([a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.\\_]+)'+'(\\@)([a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]+)'+'(\\.)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})$"
```

but I have as email address `test@test.com`, so the regexp does not match.

So I have two prolems:

- What's wrong here?
- And how can I define a error message on my own, because display this to the user, that is not a good thing :-)

Thank you in advance for your help and Best Regards.

Comment: What version of Spring MVC are you using?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you use [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html) you can use [@Email annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/api/org/hibernate/validator/Email.html) Anyway you can create your custom contraint annotation and set a custom message to show in your resource properties file.

Comment: +1 I'd highly recommend using a pre-built @Email annotation. No point in doing this on your own.

Comment: I added `@Email` annotation believing it would manage all automatically. I'm wrong. What's the sense of using this annotation if I have to add anyway a `@Pattern`?

Comment: Add to your class path the hibernate-validator.jar (if using Maven check Bassem's answer). It will automatically intercept any field or property annotated with the @Email annotation.

Comment: The @Email annotation tells me that "john@test" is a valid email address. This answer explains why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459474/hibernate-validator-email-accepts-askstackoverflow-as-valid

Comment: @Email also accepts [`null` and empty string as valid](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/AbstractEmailValidator.java#L51). So, you may also want to add @NotNull and @NotEmpty.

Answer (score 9):

First try simpler regex such as this:

```
"\\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}\\b"
```

Than you can try RFC 2822 version:

```
"(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])"
```

Let me know if the either worked for you.

Also take look at this package

```
org.springmodules.validation.bean.conf.loader.annotation.handler
```

here
http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/spring-modules-validation-module.html

It might be better alternative.

Comment: The second works, but I get another error... I have to look what is the problem `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: validation failed for classes [com.mydomain.myproject.domain.Person] during update time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]`

Comment: But no response. I created a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675204/javax-validation-constraintviolationexception-validation-failed-for-classes-duri because I do not why this error occurs. If I check the object, no failures, but on committing the object to update, the error occurs.

Comment: I updated it the new question. The new problem only occurs if I put the `@Pattern` into my Person domain object.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `@Email` from [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: `@Email` has issues. Check out this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50535214/javax-validation-constraints-email-matching-invalid-email-address

Answer (score 2):

Your regex has a couple of instances of `'+'` in it, which is kind of odd.  e-mail addresses aren't usually required to have single quotes in them :)  I think perhaps that is meant to be concatenating pieces of the String, and those should be double quotes?

For defining your own message, you just add `message="{someWay.of.definingCodes}"` to the annotation.  Then define a translation for it in `ValidationMessages.properties` in the default package.

Alternately hibernate validator provides `org.hibernate.validator.Email` if you're willing to depend on a vendor extension.

Comment: I added the message, and I created a `ValidationMessages.properties` file in my WEB-INF/messages folder with the content: `someWay.of.definingCodes=test`. But the result is `{someWay.of.definingCodes}` instead of `test`...

Comment: the default package is generally located at WEB-INF\classes :)

Comment: Oh, okay, in my Eclipse IDE the WEB-INF\classes directory seems to be empty, because I can not open it. Should I create a new file named `ValidationMessages.properties` into it?

Comment: Usually you'd leave it in the sources and let the build process move it there.  If you're using Maven you'd put it in the resources directory.  Otherwise just at the root of your sources.

Comment: I use Maven, I put it into the resources folder, and it works, thank you!