# javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: validation failed for classes during update time for groups

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc

I have a Java / Spring MVC 3 application, using Hibernate and a MySQL database.
In my controller, I have this source code:

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<Person>> failures = validator.validate(p);
if (failures.isEmpty()) {
    Project project = this.projectService.findProjectById(projectid);
    Person newPerson = this.personService.addPerson(p);

    Set<Person> persons = this.personService.getAllPersonsByProjectId(projectid);
    persons.add(newPerson);
    project.setPersons(persons);
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Project>> failures1 = validator.validate(project);
    if (!failures1.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("ERROR");
    } else {
        System.out.println("NO ERROR");
    }

    this.projectService.updateProject(project);
    return Collections.singletonMap("person", newPerson);
}
```

Project and Person are a many-to-many relation annotated with `@manytomany` and Project is the mapping owner.
The new Person is added, but on the line with `this.projectService.updateProject(project);` I get an error. What it does it this in a Dao Hibernate implementation:

```
public void updateProject(Project p) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session sess = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Transaction tx = sess.beginTransaction();
    sess.update(p);
    tx.commit();
}
```

It failed on the line `tx.commit();`. My check with `if (!failures1.isEmpty()) {` tell me that there are nor errors in my project.

So what's wrong here? And why there is a validation of my project? I did not call a validation method... so why is there a `org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate()`?

I hope, someone can help me how to fix this!

Best Regards, Tim.

Here the full error stack trace:

```
13.01.2011 00:06:36 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SERVE: Servlet.service() for servlet project3 threw exception
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: validation failed for classes [com.mydomain.myproject.domain.Person] during update time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:155)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreUpdate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:102)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.preUpdate(EntityUpdateAction.java:235)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:86)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:185)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
at com.mydomain.myproject.dao.impl.ProjectDaoImplHibernate.updateProject(ProjectDaoImplHibernate.java:44)
at com.mydomain.myproject.service.impl.ProjectServiceImpl.updateProject(ProjectServiceImpl.java:39)
at com.mydomain.myproject.controller.ProjectPersonController.addPerson(ProjectPersonController.java:189)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:195)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:159)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:141)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:90)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:417)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

13.01.2011 00:06:36 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SERVE: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: validation failed for classes [com.mydomain.myproject.domain.Person] during update time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:155)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreUpdate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:102)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.preUpdate(EntityUpdateAction.java:235)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:86)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:185)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
at com.mydomain.myproject.dao.impl.ProjectDaoImplHibernate.updateProject(ProjectDaoImplHibernate.java:44)
at com.mydomain.myproject.service.impl.ProjectServiceImpl.updateProject(ProjectServiceImpl.java:39)
at com.mydomain.myproject.controller.ProjectPersonController.addPerson(ProjectPersonController.java:189)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:195)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:159)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:141)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:90)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:417)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

**UPDATE**
Before updating the Project where the error occurs, I add a person which have this annotated:

```
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Pattern(regexp="(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])", 
        message="{my.email.error.message}")
private String email;
```

Without the `@Pattern` no error... So, what's wrong here?

**UPDATE-2**:

I use Hibernate 3.6.0.Final and I have these in my Maven pom.xml:

```
<!--  JSR 303 with Hibernate Validator -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I updated my question with these information.

Comment: In my update on my question, I already answer it: `Hibernate 3.6.0.Final`

Comment: What should I write for `flag`? And why is this Hibernate stuff, I imported `import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;`? And with `regex` instead of `regexp` I get an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the Flag as well like this: `@Pattern(regexp=..., flags={Flag.CASE_INSENSITIVE})`

More detail on flag:
http://jackson.codehaus.org/javadoc/bean-validation-api/1.0/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.Flag.html

Comment: What should I write for ``flag? And why is this Hibernate stuff, I imported`javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;`? And with `regex` instead of `regexp` I get an error.

Comment: Okay, but what should I do with the flags? Ah, I tested the 3.6.1-SNAPSHOT of Hibernate insteaf of 3.6.0.Final -> Same error, but I get the additional message: `List of constraint violations:[ ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='MyErrorMessage', propertyPath=email, rootBeanClass=class com.mydomain.myproject.domain.Person, messageTemplate='{my.email.error.message}'}
]` So, it is definitely the Pattern which causes the error.

Comment: It is defined in the properties, but you can ignore it, because without the message, I also get the error... I also updated my question, because `@NotNull` and `@Size` are already annotated.

Comment: File: `ValidationMessages.properties`, but I can remove the message parameter from the @Pattern, the error still occurs, so that is not the problem. - No change using `flags={Flag.CASE_INSENSITIVE}`.

Comment: Oh... I have the error, aaaaargh... I read the person's object into `Set<Person> persons`, and one of these person objects has a  mail address which did not match the pattern. This was added, trying "a not so hard regex" for email addresses. Oh, I'd give you ten up-votes for your help and your time. I accept your answer... I am so sorry, that was really really my fault!