# Require specific domain from email property in entity

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to validate a user entry if the email has specific domain after `@` sign instead of i.e. `gmail` I would like to allow the registration to the user if he will use `@outlook.com`.

```java
class User {
 @Email
 @NotBlank
 private String email;
}
```

Comment: regex expression using `@Pattern`

Comment: Maybe you can find answer in [Java / Spring MVC 3 validation of an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674682/java-spring-mvc-3-validation-of-an-email-address)