# ConstraintValidatorContext to define custom error messages

Tags: java, spring, validation, constraints

I want to create custom email validator using annotations. [This solution was useful while creating the validator.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32407119/3105520)
Here's the annotation :

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE,           ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {CommonsEmailValidator.class})
@Documented
@ReportAsSingleViolation
public @interface ExEmailValidator {

String message() default "        {org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email.message}";

Class<?>[] groups() default {};

Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE,          ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface List {
ExEmailValidator[] value();
}
}
```

And here's the class CommonsEmailValidator :

```
public class CommonsEmailValidator implements         ConstraintValidator<ExEmailValidator, String> {
private static final boolean ALLOW_LOCAL = false;
private EmailValidator realValidator =        EmailValidator.getInstance(ALLOW_LOCAL);

@Override
public void initialize(ExEmailValidator email) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub  
}
@Override
public boolean isValid(String email, ConstraintValidatorContext         constraintValidatorContext) {
 if( email == null ) return true;
 return realValidator.isValid(email);
 }

 }
```

I run the project, but, when I click submit on the registration form, while the email format is not valid I have the following exception :

Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [...] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]

[image: error 500]

the exception was as excpected, But instead of showing a 500 error, I would like to see an error message explaning what's wrong.
So, I think I have to use ConstraintValidatorContext to define custom error messages. But, I don't know how to do it.
Any ideas please ?

Comment: And your problem is? There is an exception because it is invalid, as you would expect, so I don't see the problem you have. One thing is you have a lot of leading spaces in the `message` value on your annotation.

Comment: Yes, the exception was as excpected, But instead of showing a 500 error, I would like to see an error message explaning what's wrong. and that doesn't allow the user to click submit until he enter a well formed email

Comment: Validation is done on the server, not on the client, so you will have to press submit to trigger the validation.

Comment: Ah okay. and what about the cutom error message? please check the post I edited it.

Comment: Assuming you are using Spring MVC, add `@Valid` to the method argument you want to validate.

Comment: Do you mean, in the controller ? I should add @Valid to a certain email argument there ?

Comment: No to your model object ... I assume you are using binding to an object and not passing in regular argument.s

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111432/discussion-between-najoua-and-m-deinum).

Answer (score 1):

You should use `@ControllerAdvice` and handle validation exceptions there with `@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)` for example.