# javax.validation.constraints.Email matching invalid email address

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-validator

I have a `User` entity having email property annotated with `@Email`

```
@Email
private String email;
```

I am using `@Valid` (javax.validation.Valid) annotation on my Controller class. The issue is that the controller validator is passing the invalid emails. Example:
**pusp@1** - obviously this is an invalid email address
**pusp@fake**
The pattern I noticed is, the `@Email` only want **sometext@text**, it don't care for the extensions(.com/org etc). Is it the expected behaviour? Do I need to pass my own regex implementation for `@Email(regex="")`

Comment: Both of your "obviously invalid" addresses are in fact legal (if not generally very useful).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A email without `.` may be considered as valid according to the validators.
In a general way, validator implementations (here it is probably the Hibernate Validator) are not very restrictive about emails.
For example the [`org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.AbstractEmailValidator`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/api/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/AbstractEmailValidator.html) javadoc states :

> The specification of a valid email can be found in [RFC 2822](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) and one
>   can come up with a regular expression matching all valid email
>   addresses as per specification. **However, as [this article](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) discusses it
>   is not necessarily practical to implement a 100% compliant email
>   validator.** This implementation is a trade-off trying to match most
>   email while ignoring for example emails with double quotes or
>   comments.

And as a side note, I noticed similarly things with HTML Validator for emails.

So I think that the behavior that you encounter actually is which one expected.
And about your question :

> *Do I need to pass my own regex implementation for @Email(regex="")*

Indeed. You don't have any other choice if you want to make the validation more restrictive.
As alternative, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12515543/270371) creating its own validator via a constraints composition is really interesting  as it is DRY (you can reuse your custom `ConstraintValidator` without specified at each time the pattern as it will be included in) and it reuses the "good part" of the `@Email` `ConstraintValidator` :

```
@Email(message="Please provide a valid email address")
@Pattern(regexp=".+@.+\\..+", message="Please provide a valid email address")
@Target( { METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@Documented
public @interface ExtendedEmailValidator {
    String message() default "Please provide a valid email address";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Comment: Just as a note, if you like to customize your error message when using ExtendedEmailValidator, you should add the `@ReportAsSingleViolation` annotation as explained here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-constraint-composition

Comment: @regisxp  `@ReportAsSingleViolation` without this my default message didn't display. Now I have message for my REST API. This answer is approved ;)

Comment: You could also create a validator using the [InternetAddress](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/apidocs/jakarta/mail/internet/internetaddress#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,boolean)) class with strict parsing enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can simply add

```
@Email(regexp = ".+[@].+[\\.].+")
```

to the column you want to be validated.

Comment: That regexp is very forgiving f.e. it will match an email that starts and ends with a dot

Comment: You are right, that's a very simple regex checking for any character followed by @ and .
It can match very strange email addresses f.e. +@+.+
To write a specific regex we have to also define the rules for a valid email address.