# javax.validation.constraints.Email rules applied to the field it is used

Tags: java

Can I find a documentation where there are all the rules that the annotation @Email from javax.validation.constraints do for the field it is used.

I tried to find, but without success.

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50535214/javax-validation-constraints-email-matching-invalid-email-address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check those pages;

[http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=380)

[JRS-380](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=380)

[AbstractEmailValidator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/api/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/AbstractEmailValidator.html)